# ionic post in rest service error with Cors enabled service

Tags: angular, rest, ionic-framework, nancy

Hello I'm a newbie in ionic.I want to call post service in ionic but I always get this error ;
""

> Failed to load http://mywebservice.com/api: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I have enable Cors in my web service (nancyfx) Even I check it on advanced Rest Service .[image]

And call post service in ionic ;

```
     let headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers = headers
        .set("Accept", "application/json")
        .set("Content-Type", "application/json")     
        const params = new HttpParams();
        const options = { headers, params, withCredentials: true };
return this.http
  .post(
    "mywebservice.com/api", headers, options
  )do(res => console.log(res)); 
enter code here
```

Any help is appricated,thanks !

Comment: When you tested on advanced rest client, did you include cookies to simulate the `withCredentials` setting?

Comment: Yes I installed https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-cookie-exchange/apcedakaoficjlofohhcmkkljehnmebp/related in order to use with arc

Comment: When you open the network debugger in chrome do see the header value set to * for your request with the credentials? It's probably some kind of misconfiguration  on nancyfx

Comment: Yes you are right ,I guess its about the nancyfx configuration.I will do something and Ill write here if its successfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve my problem by adding these in web.config (enable cors in my webservice ,nancyfx) ,(be aware of adding your custom headers to the Access-Control-Allow-Headers)

```
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:8100"/>
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Content-Disposition, mycustomheaders!" />
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"/>
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your ionic .config() you need to set below lines

```
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
```

Comment: There is no ionic.config in my directorty.Do you mean ionic.config.json ? its just this in ionic.config.json file {
  "name": "testmobile2018",
  "app_id": "",
  "type": "ionic-angular",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  }
}

Comment: its .config() of your app where you define app states/routes and basic settings of ionic.